# Cannot import NavigationToolbar from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm running a program that I received from a friend but I'm not able to solve this error. The initial part of the code is:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('GTK')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.axes import Subplot
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import FigureCanvasGTK, NavigationToolbar, NavigationToolbar2GTK

from numpy import zeros
import gtk
import gtk.glade

import scipy
import scipy.interpolate
import scipy.io
```

When I try to run the code, I receive this error:

```
File "analeem.py", line 11, in <module>
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import FigureCanvasGTK, NavigationToolbar, NavigationToolbar2GTK
ImportError: cannot import name NavigationToolbar
```

I'm running the code under Ubuntu, matplotlib is installed.

Thanks in advance,

Matteo